# Load different data in popup on buttotn click for different rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table which shows multiple rows data taken from database.

[image: View of my actual page]

There is one button in every row. So what i want, when i click on the button it should be show a popup and data would be shown of that particular row.
for example, when i click on button on the first row, popup with the data of first row will be shown.if i click the button on second row, the data of second row will be shown.

The problem is, when i click on the button of the first row or second row i am getting the same data in the popup of two different row.

[image: popup for first and second row both give same result which is the data of the first row]

so, how can i get the different data in every popup related to different rows?

**This my code of view in which i have taken value from controller and shown**

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function get_job()
        {
            $data['result'] = $this->user_model->view_job();
            if (!empty($data['result'])) 
            {
                $this->load->view('admin_view',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                $data['result'] = $this->user_model->get_username($email);
                $this->load->view('no_job',$data);
            }
        }
```

**MODEL**

```
//To get recently added jobs by inner join
    public function view_job()
    {
        $this->db->select('add_job.*, crm_accounts.company');
        $this->db->from('add_job');
        $this->db->join('crm_accounts', 'add_job.cid = crm_accounts.id', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('add_job.status', 'NEW');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Job Id</th>
                        <th>Job Name</th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Company Id</th>
                        <th>More</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                      <?php
                        foreach ($result as $object) 
                        {
                      ?>
                        <td><?php echo $object['id']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['job_id']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['job_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['company']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['cid']?></td>
                        <td>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">
                            Details
                          </button>
                        </td>
                          </tr>
                          <div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                  <div class="modal-title"><h3>Company Name :<?php echo $object['company']?></h3></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  <h3>Id:           <?php echo $object['id']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Job Name:     <?php echo $object['job_name']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Job Id:       <?php echo $object['job_id']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Paper Size:   <?php echo $object['paper_size']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Paper Type:   <?php echo $object['paper_type']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Cutting Size: <?php echo $object['cutting_size']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Sheet:        <?php echo $object['sheet']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Lamination:   <?php echo $object['lamination']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Print Type:   <?php echo $object['print_type']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Ctp By:       <?php echo $object['ctp_by']?></h3>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                <form method="post" action="admin_view">
                                  <button type="button" name="accepted" value="accept" class="btn btn-success">Accept Job</button>
                                </form>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Reject Job</button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>

                    </tbody>

                  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for same modal is opening each time you click on different row's button is the same ID of each modal.
 What you need to do is change the `data-target` of modal to be different for each row. To do this append `counter` or the `ID` or the row after the DIV ID of the modal.

Like this,

Your button code will look something like this,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal<?php echo $object['id']?>">
     Details
</button>
```

And code of Modal will look something like this,

```
<div id="MyModal<?php echo $object['id']?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <h3>Company Name :<?php echo $object['company']?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Id:           <?php echo $object['id']?></h3>
                <h3>Job Name:     <?php echo $object['job_name']?></h3>
                <h3>Job Id:       <?php echo $object['job_id']?></h3>
                <h3>Paper Size:   <?php echo $object['paper_size']?></h3>
                <h3>Paper Type:   <?php echo $object['paper_type']?></h3>
                <h3>Cutting Size: <?php echo $object['cutting_size']?></h3>
                <h3>Sheet:        <?php echo $object['sheet']?></h3>
                <h3>Lamination:   <?php echo $object['lamination']?></h3>
                <h3>Print Type:   <?php echo $object['print_type']?></h3>
                <h3>Ctp By:       <?php echo $object['ctp_by']?></h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form method="post" action="admin_view">
                    <button type="button" name="accepted" value="accept" class="btn btn-success">Accept Job</button>
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Reject Job</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Alok for this explaination . I totaly understood this and this solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great @DharaVihol, please accept it as correct answer if it solved your problem for future SO users.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Job Id</th>
                        <th>Job Name</th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Company Id</th>
                        <th>More</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                      <?php
                        foreach ($result as $object) 
                        {
                      ?>
                        <td><?php echo $object['id']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['job_id']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['job_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['company']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $object['cid']?></td>
                        <td>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal_<?php echo $object['id']?>">
                            Details
                          </button>
                        </td>
                          </tr>
                          <div id="MyModal_<?php echo $object['id']?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                  <div class="modal-title"><h3>Company Name :<?php echo $object['company']?></h3></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  <h3>Id:           <?php echo $object['id']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Job Name:     <?php echo $object['job_name']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Job Id:       <?php echo $object['job_id']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Paper Size:   <?php echo $object['paper_size']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Paper Type:   <?php echo $object['paper_type']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Cutting Size: <?php echo $object['cutting_size']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Sheet:        <?php echo $object['sheet']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Lamination:   <?php echo $object['lamination']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Print Type:   <?php echo $object['print_type']?></h3>
                                  <h3>Ctp By:       <?php echo $object['ctp_by']?></h3>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                <form method="post" action="admin_view">
                                  <button type="button" name="accepted" value="accept" class="btn btn-success">Accept Job</button>
                                </form>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Reject Job</button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>

                    </tbody>

                  </table>


   Try this code. i thing. you problem will resolved.
```

Comment: Thank you Rajeev for your help. your answer is also right but Alok explained it very well.